# Is it advised to use my own implementation of a push-notifications rather than a third party one in production?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, socket.io, pusher

I want to implement notifications in a Node.js back-end and mobile front-ends and I'm planning to use Socket.io to implement this functionality. After deployment the apps will have near 20,000 users. Is it advised to use some third party solutions ( like Firebase ...) or it is okay with this approach? If it's okay does that require much higher requirements for the server?

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel, unless you plan on learning more about wheels](https://blog.codinghorror.com/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels/).

Comment: @VLAZ Such third party services are paid, and are not cheap. All I want to know is if implementing it myself can be as efficient as those services.

Comment: Are you prepared to invest at least a fraction of the time many other people have poured into a third party service? I'm not trying to say "don't do it" but do seriously consider the fact that a ready product would have A LOT less bugs than something you do yourself. And not because you're somehow bad - the other product would have been used and tested for a lot longer. You might hit some issue that utterly perplexes you as it did the other developers, yet they solved it years ago and have had time to improve their solution, while you're just now starting to think about it.